# Split column into multiple column based on string condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-slicing

This is how the data set looks like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEr5d.png)

I have a column for 4000's values which contain different values in that column such as shown in the image.

I want to split the dataset based on the string compare. My ultimate goal is get all the values of W_LD(1) to W_LD(57) to put in one column, similarly others such as R_LD(1) to R_LD(32) into different column and so on.

I am creating a dataframe and try to match the string if the string matches particular value then all the values should go into different column.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
str_x = df.Device_names[56]
def my_split(df):
    return pd.Series 
({'W_LD': [i for i in df.Device_names if str_x == "^W_LD(57)"] })
df.apply(my_split, axis=1)
```

Comment: Some example input and desired output? I am not clear on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please read the statement again. I have made changes